# How do I propagate my hops?

Tags: hops, growing-hops

I have a couple plants going, but I am ready to get more of the same varieties going in the future.
How do I go about getting more plants from the same plants I already have?
Can I take a cutting?
Can I just bury a fresh bine out to the side?
Do I dig up and chop up the rhizome at the end of the season?

Help me get my hop yard going!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I googled around a bit and came up with this:

At the end of the season healthy bottom vines can be buried for the propagation of new plants the next spring. Simply bury the vines in a shallow trench and mark their location. In spring dig them up and cut them into pieces about 4 inches long. Make sure each new cutting has an eye or bud.

It sounds easy enough...

Found at [homebrewtalk](http://www.homebrewtalk.com/wiki/index.php/Hop_cultivation#Root_pruning_and_propogation)

Answer (score 2):

You can bury bines at the end of the season - a couple inches deep.  You mention these are established hop plants so if you cut a circle around the bines - say 12 inch radius, 2 or three inches deep and pull up the rhizomes on the outside of that circle, cut them in 4 to 6 inch sections and [plant the hop rhizomes](http://www.growinghopsyourself.com/growing-hops/growing-hops-from-rhizomes/) where you want to expand your hops, that is the best way.  The rhizomes will be just under the soil and possibly on top running out from the crown.